# How to apply LiveData to xxxFragment.class instead of XML

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, swiperefreshlayout

How to apply *live data* **isRefreshing** to `swiperefreshLayout.isRefresh`?

Code in `xxxViewModel.class`:

```
var isRefreshing = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

fun refresh() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        isRefreshing.value = true

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            fun doInBackground() // takes a long time
        }
   
        isRefreshing.value = false
    }
}
```

Code in `xxxFragment.class`:

```
binding.swiperefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
    xxxViewModel.refresh()
}

// error here, require Boolean, found MutableLiveData<Boolean>
binding.swiperefreshLayout.isRefreshing = xxxViewModel.isRefreshing
```

Usually I apply the live data to XML like below, but I cannot find `swiperefreshlayout.isRefreshing` in XML.

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        isFreshing = "@{xxxViewModel.isRefreshing}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is to get the current value of the liveData "isRefreshing". (also you need to add .value to get the underlying value associated with the liveData)

```
binding.swiperefreshLayout.isRefreshing = xxxViewModel.isRefreshing.value?:false
```

Instead, you should observe the Live Data for changes after initializing your view model.

```
 xxxViewModel.apply {

    
    isRefreshing.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
         binding.swiperefreshLayout.isRefreshing = it
    }

    //... observe the rest of your LiveData
}
```

EDIT:

you can create a function like the following

```
private inline fun <T> doObserve(ld: LiveData<T>, crossinline callback: (T) -> Unit) {
    ld.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { callback.invoke(it) })
}
```

then just call that instead

```
 xxxViewModel.apply {

   doObserve( isRefreshing){
         binding.swiperefreshLayout.isRefreshing = it
    }

    //... observe the rest of your LiveData
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million. I have so many LiveData, do I have to type "viewLifecycleOwner" for each one?

Comment: I mean, is there a way to get rid of "viewLifecycleOwner" and "binding", move to apply portion, so I only need to type xxx.oberve { swiperefreshLayout.isRefreshing = it}

Comment: @caibirdcnb you can create a function for that (see updated answer)